# Delete Rows from Pandas DataFrame with matching column but not index

Tags: python, pandas

Basically I have a list of inventory from devices, what I need to do is find out which is mirrored and which isn't. It is indexed by device at the moment.

```
     Device                              MedDescription
    RWC6NOR1                    amLODIPine (NORVASC) 2.5 mg Tab
    RWC6NOR1    Carbidopa/Levodopa (SINEMET) 25 mg (100 mg) Tab
    RWC6NOR1                   Bisacodyl EC (DULCOLAX) 5 mg Tab
    RWC6NOR1                     Lovastatin (MEVACOR) 10 mg Tab
    RWC6NOR2       Doxycycline Monohydrate (AVIDOXY) 100 mg Tab
    RWC6NOR2                    amLODIPine (NORVASC) 2.5 mg Tab
    RWC6NOR2    Carbidopa/Levodopa (SINEMET) 25 mg (100 mg) Tab
    RWC6NOR2                   Bisacodyl EC (DULCOLAX) 5 mg Tab
    RWC6NOR2                     Lovastatin (MEVACOR) 10 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU1       Doxycycline Monohydrate (AVIDOXY) 100 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU1                    amLODIPine (NORVASC) 2.5 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU1    Carbidopa/Levodopa (SINEMET) 25 mg (100 mg) Tab
    RWC6SOU1                   Bisacodyl EC (DULCOLAX) 5 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU1                     Lovastatin (MEVACOR) 10 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU1       Doxycycline Monohydrate (AVIDOXY) 100 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU1                    amLODIPine (NORVASC) 2.5 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU2    Carbidopa/Levodopa (SINEMET) 25 mg (100 mg) Tab
    RWC6SOU2                   Bisacodyl EC (DULCOLAX) 5 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU2                     Lovastatin (MEVACOR) 10 mg Tab
    RWC6SOU2       Doxycycline Monohydrate (AVIDOXY) 100 mg Tab
```

So what I am trying to is basically compare the med description column with the index and if there is a match between two Devices(6NOR1 AND 6NOR2) I want to remove both of them from the dataframe.

For example AMLODIPINE 2.5MG is both in 6NOR1 AND 6NOR2 it would there for be removed, and it would look like this:

```
    Device                              MedDescription
   RWC6NOR2       Doxycycline Monohydrate (AVIDOXY) 100 mg Tab
```

Some potential ways I was thinking I could do that is by get the Device column and then get all the unique values from there. After which I can use the query function to loop through and query specific units by themselves.

THEN...I am lost.

Thank you for your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's not already, make sure that 'Device' is a column, not the `DataFrame` index (using `df = df.reset_index()`)

Then, your entire operation is a relatively clean [`groupy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine) operation.

`query` filters to the devices you mentioned, `groupby` partitions the data by unique 'MedDescription', and `filter` keeps only those groups with one of the two devices.  See the linked docs for more examples / possibilities.

```
In [28]: (df.query("Device in ['RWC6NOR1','RWC6NOR2']")
    ...:    .groupby('MedDescription')
    ...:    .filter(lambda x: x['Device'].nunique() == 1))

Out[28]: 
     Device                                MedDescription
4  RWC6NOR2  Doxycycline Monohydrate (AVIDOXY) 100 mg Tab
```

Comment: sorry for the newb question, but what exactly will this groupby do? I understand it creates a list of groupby objects from the documentation, but what exactly does that mean?

Comment: I'd encourage spending some time with docs as it really steps through it.  The `groupby` doesn't do anything by itself, it just describes, "this is how I want to partition my data".  Whatever you call after groupby, actually does something to those partions - in this case `filter`, (exluding some partitions), but it could also be an `aggregation` (summarizing entire partition), or a `transform` (modifying all the values)